# Set Android owner password programmatically

Tags: android

Assuming that I have root permissions is there any way to programmatically set the Owner password/pin without any user interaction?  The API level I have to work with is 17 or 18.

Comment: Look up "Device Admin" for android, Or Device Policy Manager. With some code in your application, if the user activates your application as a device admin then the app can change the Device Password. ********This does not require your device to be rooted.**********

Comment: Thanks Ill try that

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Device Admin Code
Add this in your xml folder:

**device_admin.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<device-admin xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
<uses-policies>
    <!--<limit-password />-->
    <!--<watch-login />-->
    <reset-password />
    <force-lock />
    <wipe-data />
   <!-- <expire-password />
    <encrypted-storage />-->
    <!--<disable-camera />-->
    <!--<disable-keyguard-features />-->
</uses-policies>
```

These are the different policies you can have in your app. Uncomment whichever you need. Reset password and force lock are the once you want.

**Inside your activity:**

```
DevicePolicyManager mDPM;
ComponentName mAdminName;
.......
mDPM = (DevicePolicyManager) getSystemService(Context.DEVICE_POLICY_SERVICE);
mAdminName = new ComponentName(this, MyAdminReceiver.class);
```

Use this code to check whether your app has Device admin capabilities, if not direct user to the respective page.

```
if (!mDPM.isAdminActive(mAdminName)) {
                // try to become active – must happen here in this activity, to get result
                Intent intent = new Intent(DevicePolicyManager.ACTION_ADD_DEVICE_ADMIN);
                intent.putExtra(DevicePolicyManager.EXTRA_DEVICE_ADMIN,
                        mAdminName);
                intent.putExtra(DevicePolicyManager.EXTRA_ADD_EXPLANATION, "Your Explanation for requesting these Admin Capabilities.");
                startActivityForResult(intent, REQUEST_ENABLE);
            }
```

Finally to lock your phone :

```
//Reset Password
mDPM.resetPassword(newPassword, DevicePolicyManager.RESET_PASSWORD_REQUIRE_ENTRY);
//Lock Phone
mDPM.lockNow();
```

DONE